# bash - ftp - 501 PORT address does not match originator

Tags: bash, ftp, upload

Having some troubles trying to put a file onto my web server. Using what I've learned from

http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/programming-scripting/106665-automatic-ftp-upload-via-script.html

I created a script as follows:

```
hostname='ftp.edwardleuf.org'
username='*'
password='*'

ftp -n -v $hostname << EOT
ascii
user $username $password
prompt
cd /
put mainscheme
bye
EOT
```

And I get the following result:

```
Connected to accessproxy.webpod3-cph3.one.com.
220 Welcome to One.com FTP.
502 'TYPE': command not implemented.
331 User * OK. Password required
230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
Interactive mode off.
250 OK. Current directory is /
local: mainscheme remote: mainscheme
501 PORT address does not match originator.  << ??
ftp: bind: Address already in use
221 Goodbye.
```

What does this mean, and what can I do to get the file uploaded? (Server runs on port 21 when using other FTP applications)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to make sure you are using passive mode for connecting and  transferring.

Comment: This should be a comment, please make it so.

Comment: What a little `-p` can do. ;) @heemayl this solved it!

Comment: @Edward Still, it's a low quality answer to me, without any explanation at all especially why you would need the passive mode and so on.